# Spring RestTemplate starts returning 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED after URL change at run time

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am facing an interesting problem in a service class in my Spring Boot application. My service communicates with an external system. When I change the URL of the external API at run time via Spring Actuator, the `RestTemplate` starts returning `405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED` response code. To summarize, here is what I am doing:

- Run my app with the correct external API URL (read from `application.properties`)
- Call my service via Postman: this call is successful and I get the correct response from the external system
- Call my custom actuator service to change the external API URL, and make it invalid
- Call my service again: this time I get `UnknownHostException`, which is correct
- Call actuator service to change the URL back to its original (correct) value
- Call my service again: now `RestTemplate` starts returning `405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED` response code, which I don't understand.

I am using the `RestTemplate` in `MyService` as follows:

```
private <T> ResponseEntity<T> send(HttpEntity<?> entity, Class<T> responseClass) {
    try {
        return restTemplate.exchange(serviceSettings.getUrl(), HttpMethod.POST, entity, responseClass);
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        // Handle exception
    }
}
```

where the `RestTemplate` is created in the service constructor by using `RestTemplateBuilder#build`.

I enabled debug logging to see what's going on, but it also doesn't say much. I have extracted the relevant info from the logs:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - HTTP POST 'https://correct-external-api-url'
DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Writing [{data=[PD94bWwg...
DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Response 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
```

And there is nothing else between these log entries. `SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest` seems to open the connection with correct URL and HTTP method, but I still end up getting 405 response.

For completeness, my custom actuator end-point looks like this:

```
@Service
@Endpoint(id="service-settings")
public class SettingsService {

    private final ServiceSettings serviceSettings;

    public PspSettingsService(ServiceSettings serviceSettings) {
        this.serviceSettings = serviceSettings;
    }

    @WriteOperation
    public void changeUrl(String newUrl) {
        serviceSettings.setUrl(newUrl);
    }
}
```

I am using `Spring Boot 2.2.4.RELEASE`. Any help / feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Please do some debug on the url and then you'll see which value it assume

Comment: It's an external system, I don't have access to it. As far as I could debug within the Spring framework, I am opening the connection with the correct URL.